# How to add data from Laravel using a ReactJs component?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm trying to add Laravel existing conditional statement on ReactJs component

I've tried to add it on render function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="login">
                @if (Route::has('login'))
                    <div class="top-right links">
                        @auth
                            <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                        @else
                            <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
                            /*-- <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                                @if (Route::has('register'))
                            @endif */
                        @endauth
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('login')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('login'));
}
```

```
<div id="login"> </div>
```

```
require('./components/Welcome');
```

I'm trying to display the existing laravel script from react components.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: @if is used by blade template engine and react use jsx or ts which is not possible to use blade template codes try to use js if condition

Comment: This problem were months ago. Thanks for this information sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@if` use by blade template which output is `<?php if(condition) ?>`

you can try this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="login">

                    <div class="top-right links">
                       if (isLoggedIn) {
                            <a href="/home">Home</a>
                        } else {
                            <a href="/login">Login</a>

                        }
                    </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('login')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('login'));
}
```

`isLoggedIn` is coming from state of react where should true when user is logged in

Comment: Sorry It was weeks ago, I forgot this problem on my notes.

Thanks anyway for the help.